# Bring Emacs frame to front when running emacsclient on WSL

Tags: frames, emacsclient, wsl, x-window

Currently using Emacs on [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).
I have this alias for `emacsclient` executable:

```
alias e='emacsclient -n'
```

Which I run very often when I am on the terminal (I use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) or [terminator](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

The problem is that whenever I execute it, Emacs windows is not brought to front.
So I have to search for it with `Alt+TAB`...
Which I find a bit annoying when I have a bunch of windows opened.

Is there a way to bring Emacs to front when running `emacsclient` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of  quirky way of achieving it, but it worked for me.
Having `frame-title-format` set to its original value:

```
(setq frame-title-format '(multiple-frames "%b"
                                           ("" invocation-name "@" system-name)))
```

shows this on `wmctrl` utility to interact with X-Windows manager:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x00e00003  0 ES-00002604 /bin/bash
0x0120001d  0 ES-00002604 emacs@ES-00002604
```

So, writing this short bash script `e.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacsclient -n $1
wmctrl -a nephewtom
```

And having this `alias` defined:

```
alias e='e.sh'
```

Allows me to work like this:

[image]